What's a good test network right now?
I'm currently looking for a reliable test network for Ethereum. Could you recommend a good one to use right now? And how do i access the RInkeby test network?
Thanks!

Rinkeby testnet is deprecated. The only available testnet for Ethereum as of now, is Ethereum Sepolia, having ETH Chain Id value of 11155111.
In MetaMask, you can switch to Sepolia testnet by toggling on Show test networks.
Otherwise, you can also add it using Chainlist.
For the corresponding faucet details in order to get some Sepolia ETH, you can refer to this answer.

Yup, ETH had lots of testnets but now the best and only working one is Sepolia  11155111(0xaa36a7)
Btw if you need a custom ETH Sepolia RPC URL to your Metamask you can check out this guide from GetBlock on how to do it: https://getblock.io/blog/add-ethereum-sepolia-testnet-metamask/
I'd also recommend grabbing a private RPC from GetBlock and using their free testnet faucet, it's pretty convenient!
